# Is browsing to HTML5 is through phone or computer

Tags: html, mobile, browser, user-agent, mobile-devices

How do I know whether browsing the site (built in HTML5), done by a computer or by a cell phone devices (iPhone, Android, etc.)

I know there is such thing as User Agent, but I want to know his specific line of code ..

What it shows when I'm on a computer, and what it shows when I'm on mobile phones?

Thank you

Comment: Well this clearly shows a lack of effort in researching. Google `device detection html5` and your free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
   var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };
```

More information on [this](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/) link.

But if javascript is disabled you wouldn't be able to do it like this
however,  you can perform validations or checking on the server side. but that's now up to you. Depending on the CGI you are using.

Comment: You sould be aware that this is not ideal solution, because there are milions unique mobile device User-Agents and no clear way to distinguish what makes a User-Agent mobile. For example if user is using Dolphin Browser on android you should check for Dolphin's specific user agent string. You should also be aware that often users force mobile browsers to send desktop user agent string, to see desktop version of the site.

Comment: If the user is working a simple application this would do, and besides he just wanted a sample code, if he wants a far more complex example he or she could use a framework. but thanks for the heads up